# How can I disable a specific script? (selenium python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am scraping a web page with selenium webdriver, but it's too slow, so I thought that by disabling all the unecessary scripts (for my program at least), and running with the only one I need, I could speed it up a lot. The thing is that I don't know how.

I tried using NoScript extension, but I can't enable the script I need, so everything is disabled and I get an error, because the element I'm scraping isn't there. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_extension(f"C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/Downloads/NoScript.crx")
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("www.example.link.com")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
the_element_i_need = soup.find("div", id="something")
```

Comment: I don't know, but to speed up you can try headless `options.add_argument("--headless=new")` and/or disable images  `options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')`

Comment: Oh, I know about those, I tried using headless, but for some reason, I got an error, I didn't quite understand why though. I tried to fix it anyway by searching and all, but I couldn't, and now I'm too lazy to check the error I got (jk, it's bc it takes SO many lines so it would be hard to show it here). About the disable image, well... I already do that, and it sped up my program significantly, but it still takes around a minute to load everything (bc the page I'm scraping is very script heavy, if that makes sense). I'll include more on the question itself. Anyway, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @soundwave I forgot to tag you on my previous comment, it wouldn't fit anyway lol